# htaccess unescaping chars on redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I'm making a search page which is redirecting a search to the search page.

So if somebody types `hey!@#$` and searches, the url will be `http://localhost:8888/search/hey%21%40%23%24` but the search result will be `hey!@`

However if I type the direct url `http://localhost:8888/search.php?s=hey%21%40%23%24` the result is `hey!@#$`

Which means that my redirect is unescaping characters. How can I keep the characters escaped?

Here's my htaccess code.

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?s=$1 [NC,L]
```

Edit: I don't understand the downvotes and no reasons. Is my question unclear or something?

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, by "keep the characters escaped" ?

Comment: If you print `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` it will print:  `s=hey%21%40%23%24`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%23` is interpreted as `#`, which is an anchor ([Learn more here](http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm)). For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP#Mascot goes directly to the Mascot subheading, and so does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP%23Mascot.

In other words, the #$ was not escaped in http://localhost:8888/search/hey%21%40%23%24, but rather ignored. That is why the second example seems to be "unescaped".

As for how to keep it escaped, you could try to add the 'B' tag to your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ search.php?s=$1 [B,NC,L]
```

Learn more about tags here -> https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html

Comment: Ah, I see. Since it seems that once it receives %23 it turns it into # when it redirects. Is there a way to keep it as %23?

Comment: @Trevor W: Updated the answer.